# Upload files with HTML/PHP/AJAX and especially SweetAlert2/jquery_file_upload

Tags: php, ajax, file-upload, jquery-file-upload, sweetalert

I want to upload file from HTML to my server with PHP and js library [SweetAlert2](https://github.com/limonte/sweetalert2).

It work if I do that

```
swal({
    html: '<form action="script/php/upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"><input name=\"upload[]\" id="fileToUpload" accept= "application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" multiple></input></form>'
})
```

But I don't completely use power of "SweetAlert2" so I try this **JAVASCRIPT/AJAX**

```
swal({
    input: 'file',
    inputAttributes: {
        name:"upload[]",
        id:"fileToUpload",
        accept: "application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet",
        multiple:"multiple"
    },
    showCloseButton: true,
    showCancelButton: true
}).then(function() {
    var formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileToUpload', $('#fileToUpload')[0]);
    $.ajax({type:"POST",url:"script\\php\\upload.php",data: formData,processData: false,contentType: false,headers:{"Content-Type":"multipart/form-data"},async:false});
})
```

But it doesn' work...

My **PHP** like that

```
$total = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);
echo($total);

for($i=0; $i<$total; $i++) {
  $tmpFilePath = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'][$i];

  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    $newFilePath = "d:/web/site_sig_cclo/site_3_administration/script/python/" . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i];

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
    }
  }
}
```

And `echo` always return `0`

**------EDIT 2016 10 05------**

My PHP is launched with this Post value

[image]

**------EDIT 2016 10 06------**

If I use `console.log` on my input file after that `.then(function(file) {` I've :

[image]

And if I do the same on my FormData it seems to be empty :

[image]

**------EDIT 2016 10 12------**

I try a technic with the script `jquery_file_upload`

I load **input** in my **swal**

```
swal({
    title: "Input title",
    html: '<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>'
});
```

And after I load my scripts with jquery function for `fileupload`

```
$.getScript("script/jquery_file_upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js");
$.getScript("script/jquery_file_upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js");
$.getScript("script/jquery_file_upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js", function(){
    $("#fileupload").fileupload({
        url:"script/python",
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context  = $('#fileuploadname').text('Uploading...').appendTo(document.body);
            data.submit();
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload finished.');
        }
    });
});
```

If I do `console.log` on `data` values I can see all it work, but on my server I've nothing...

[image]

Comment: I think this is wrong `script\\php\\upload.php` you don't need to escape the slashes `script/php/upload.php` should work.

Comment: Thank you for your commentary Franco but it doesn't work better

Comment: Do you got any traceable errors when you use it?

Comment: No errors, only...empty treatment

Comment: I see, in your `php file`  you are not uploading the file you want to : $_FILES['upload']  has to be $_FILES['fileToUpload']

Comment: I change that, but nothing else happend. I thought that was the name of te input attribute, not the id with `$_FILES[]`

Comment: May  I see your the form you are using to upload the file?

Comment: Sweetalert2 generate this code : `<input id="fileToUpload" multiple="multiple" style="display: block;" name="fileToUpload[]" accept="application/vnd.ms-excel,application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet" class="swal2-file" placeholder="" type="file">`

Comment: Not that, You have an `html` form that you are using to upload the files. This is the upload input. This is important in order to do this: `new FormData($('#your_form_id')[0])`

Comment: This is in the subject. In fact in html I wrote this `<button class="bouton" onclick="function('integratio')">Go to the input !</button>` and this call what I wrote in subject (`swal`) and after, SweetAlert2 generate the input.

Comment: I created a post with a solution that worked for me. You can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54481398/2291935).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to open swal function

```
swal({
    title: "Input title",
    html: '<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>'
}).then(function() {
    (...)
}
```

And after load scripts with jquery function for fileupload at the same level like swal. In this script it's necessary to call the php code for upload files

```
$.getScript("script/jquery_file_upload/js/vendor/jquery.ui.widget.js");
$.getScript("script/jquery_file_upload/js/jquery.iframe-transport.js");
$.getScript("script/jquery_file_upload/js/jquery.fileupload.js", function(){
    $("#fileupload").fileupload({
        url:"script/php/myuploadphp.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        add: function (e, data) {
            data.context  = $('#fileuploadname').text('Uploading...').appendTo(document.body);
            data.submit();
        },
        done: function (e, data) {
            data.context.text('Upload finished.');
        }
    });
});
```

And in PHP write that

```
$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][0];

      if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
        $newFilePath = "destination_folder" . $_FILES['files']['name'][0];
      }
```

And that's work !