# Sweet Alert 2 jQuery file upload with php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file

I'm trying to create a file uploader inside a Sweet Alert 2 modal with jQuery and php. Here's my code, but it isn't working: how can I get this working?

Thank you

HTML (the button to open the modal with Sweet Alert 2):

```
<button class="bx--btn bx--btn--primary" type="button" id="swal_upload">Apri</button>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#swal_upload').click(function(){
    var api = 'api/UploadFile.php';
    swal({
        title: "Carica immagine",
        html: '<input id="fileupload" type="file" name="userfile">'
    }).then(function() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('userfile', $('#fileupload').val().replace(/.*(\/|\\)/, ''));
        console.log(formData);
        $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: api,
          data: formData,
          dataType: 'json',
          processData: false,
          contentType: false,
          headers: {"Content-Type":"form-data"},
          async: true,
          success: function(result){
            console.log("OK client side");
            console.log(result.Response);
          }
        });
    })
  });
```

php (api/UploadFile.php):

```
$entered = "PHP started";

$tmpFilePath = $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'];

$uploaddir = 'public/';

  if ($tmpFilePath != ""){
    $newFilePath = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);

    if(move_uploaded_file($tmpFilePath, $newFilePath)) {
      $uploaded = "Upload OK server side";
    } else {
      $uploaded = "Upload failed server side";
    }
  }

  // Prepare response, close connection and send response to front-end
  $array['Response'] = array(
    'entered' => $entered,
    'tmp_path' => $tmpFilePath,
    'new_path' => $newFilePath,
    'file_name' => $_FILES['file']['name'],
    'uploaded' => $uploaded
  );

  echo json_encode($array);
```

The output I have in the console is:

FormData {}**proto**: FormData
OK client side
{entered: "PHP started", tmp_path: null, new_path: null, file_name: null, uploaded: null}
entered:"PHP started"
file_name:null
new_path:null
tmp_path:null
uploaded:null
**proto**:Object

As you can see the php starts, but no file is passed to the server.

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Comment: you can not use ajax to upload data this way. especially with "Content-Type":"form-data"

Comment: @PaunNarcisIulian do you have a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I used a solution based on the **input file** type from [Sweetalert 2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#input-types) and the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/FileReader)/[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects#Creating_a_FormData_object_from_scratch) objects from the view side.
When you use an input file type of Sweetalert, an input element with the `swal2-file` css class will be created:
[image]

Then you can use the Sweetalert event `onBeforeOpen` to read the file data through the FileReader object. Finally you can send the file using ajax request with the FormData object.
This would be the js source:

```
$('#swal_upload').click(function() {
     Swal({
        title: 'Select a file',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: 'Upload',
        input: 'file',
        onBeforeOpen: () => {
            $(".swal2-file").change(function () {
                var reader = new FileReader();
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
            });
        }
    }).then((file) => {
        if (file.value) {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var file = $('.swal2-file')[0].files[0];
            formData.append("fileToUpload", file);
            $.ajax({
                headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') },
                method: 'post',
                url: '/file/upload',
                data: formData,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                success: function (resp) {
                    Swal('Uploaded', 'Your file have been uploaded', 'success');
                },
                error: function() {
                    Swal({ type: 'error', title: 'Oops...', text: 'Something went wrong!' })
                }
            })
        }
    })
})
```

From the server side, using Laravel Php framework, you can get the file through a function like this:

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->hasFile('fileToUpload')) {
        $file_name = $request->file('fileToUpload')->getClientOriginalName();
        $earn_proof = $request->file('fileToUpload')->storeAs("public/files/", $file_name);
    }

    return response()->json(['result' => true], 200);
}
```