# How do I upload sweetalert photos to my database

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sweetalert2

I have a sweetalert/javascript function and I want my users to upload two images and one text to my database. I only found out how to upload images using basic HTML "file" boxes. But not how to do it with sweetalert....

This is my sweetalert/Javascript code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#new-btn').click(function() {

    swal.mixin({
      input: 'text',
      confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
      showCancelButton: true,
      progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
    }).queue([{
        input: 'file',
        inputAttributes: {
          name: "image",
          class: "image",

        },
        title: 'Profilbild hochladen',
        text: 'Empfohlen wird 1X1'
      },
      {
        input: 'file',
        title: 'Hintergrundbild hochladen',
        text: 'Empfohlen wird 16X9'
      },
      {

        title: 'Über mich',
        text: ''
      },

    ]).then((result) => {
      if (result.value) {

        var kuerzeltest = "mk304";


        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../../register/profil_update.php",
          data: {
            "post": result.value[2],
            "kuerzel": kuerzeltest
          },



        });
        $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "../../register/profil_update.php",
          data: {
            "bild": new FormData(this),
            "bild2": result.value[1],
            "kuerzel": kuerzeltest
          },
          contentType: false,
          processData: false,

        });
        swal(
          "Super!",
          "Dein Profil wurde erfolgreich aktualisiert ",
          "success"

        )
      }
    })
  });
})
```

and this is my backend code

```html
<?php
include_once '../../userdata.php';
//Posts in Datenbank schreiben


$kuerzel = $_POST["kuerzel"];
$bild = $_FILES['bild'];
$bild2 = $_FILES['bild2'];
$post = $_POST["post"];

$pdo = new PDO ($dsn, $dbuser, $dbpass, array('charset'=>'utf8'));
$sql = "INSERT INTO user_bilder (kuerzel, bild, bild2, post) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";

$statement = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$statement->execute(array("$kuerzel", "$bild", "$bild2", "$post"));

$row = $statement->fetchObject();

header("Location: ../webpage/home.php");

?>
```

My server where I run this code on https://mars.iuk.hdm-stuttgart.de/~mk304/Web_Projekt/webpage/ui/sweetalert/sweetalert_eingabe.php

I really don't know where my error is,

Comment: What is expected result and what happens if you turn on PHP error reporting?

Comment: hi @mplungjan, I want to add the images to the database

Comment: Yes, but what happens? Errors?

Comment: I created a post with a solution that worked for me. You can see it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54481398/2291935).